# What is a Rollup Table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, hierarchical-data

I'm analyzing data-schema models and doing some proof of concept tests with them. There is a lot of recursion in the schema and I think it might impact performance because data will be queried thousands of times a day but information on the tree structured base tables will only be edited once every X days.

One of the tables in the schema is a PRODUCT CATEGORY rollup and has a to and from relationship to CATEGORY.

Can it be used to keep recorder tree structures (without recursion) and what are the best ways to maintain them?

Answer (score 2):

If you have limited tree structure (levels not more than e.g. 10 and amount of children is not more than 1000) you can use char level representation and inheritance. Each node or leaf is represented by some string. Each level down increases length of the string by 3

E.g. you have

```
ROOT
-CHILD 1
--subchild 1 of child 1
--subchild 2 of child 1
-CHILD 2
--subchild 1 of child 2
--subchild 2 of child 2
```

You have a 'tree_string' for them

```
ROOT - '000'
CHILD 1 - '000 000'
CHILD 2 - '000 001'
subchild 1 of child 1 - '000 000 000'
subchild 2 of child 1 - '000 000 001'
subchild 1 of child 2 - '000 001 000'
subchild 2 of child 2 - '000 001 001'
```

Thus with the string it's easy to get all subtree using tree_string LIKE parent_string_param%

Comment: Sounds like a very good idea... are there any links to more examples of this so I can understand the possibilities of it more?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no links or examples. I used the approach in one past project several years ago. Potential problems could be editing of the hierarchy (adding children, reparenting etc. to generate proper tree_string value)

Comment: that is exactly what I was thinking of, figured observing how it works would help decide the best way to approach that